# Delphi xe-3 indy 10 unable to read data tidudpserver onudpread

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe3

i am using tidudpserver for both client and server .below is the server and client code given.

```
unit udp_server;



procedure TForm4.serverUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  AData: array of Byte; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  buffer:tbytes;
  buffer2:tbytes;
  i:integer;
  ex_port:word;
  i_ip,ex_ip:string;
  t: string;
begin
   ex_ip:=abinding.PeerIP;      //public_ip
   ex_port:=abinding.PeerPort;   //public_port

   //byte  to string
   setlength(i_ip,length(adata) div 2);  

   // extract private ip from array of byte
   move(Adata[0],i_ip[1],length(adata)); 

   // client profile  {object of tclient }
   user:=tclient.create(ex_ip,ex_port,i_ip,0,''); 
   //copying public and private    endpoints to tclient object


   setlength(buffer,sizeof(user));         
   move(user,buffer[0],sizeof(user)); // copying object to byte array 


   server.Sendbuffer(abinding.PeerIP,abinding.PeerPort,buffer); 
   // send client info to all connected clients(is this correct way of sending buffer(byte array)?)
end;
```

This is the clients code given .i am unable to read data sent by the server in `onudpread` procedure. How can i convert the byte array (which contains strings and word types) to readable text?

```
unit udp_client;



procedure TForm4.server2UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  AData: array of Byte; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  dest:string;
  user2:tclient;// i had a tclient class in a separate file
  buffer:tbytes;
begin


  setlength(dest,length(adata));
  move(Adata[0],dest[1],length(adata));  // problem is over here ,is this correct?
end;
```

private ip sent from the client

```
              ip:=getipaddress; //call private ip function taken from (http://delphi.about.com/od/networking/l/aa103100a.htm)

              setlength(i_ip,length(ip)*2);

              move(ip[1],i_ip[0],length(i_ip));

              server2.Sendbuffer('host',port,i_ip);
```

i want to do udp hole punching for that clients need to send their info(public/private ip/port) to server and then server will exchange clients info and then they should be able chat.i am confused as adata array is receiving all data would the ip's and text message get mix with each other?currently i am receiving garbage value, its like chinese.:-/

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove all of the user interface code (which is not relevant to your question). It's much harder to figure out what you're asking with all of the extra code there that has nothing to do with your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems with this code.

In the server code, you are passing the wrong Size value to `Move()` when copying the received data to a `String`. You are taking `SizeOf(Char)=2` into account when calling `SetLength()` but not when calling `Move()`.  And taking `Sizeof(Char)` into account is only correct to do if the received data is UTF-16 to begin with (you did not show what the received data actuallylooks like).

A bigger problem is that you are trying to send an object to the client, and that will never work.  You must serialize the object's individual data members into a flat transmittable format and then send that data instead. For instance, the `IdGlobal` unit has many functions available for doing data<->bytes conversions (`ToBytes()` overloads, `BytesTo...()` overloads, `CopyTId...()` overloads, etc). So you could allocate a single `TIdBytes` large enough to hold all of your object's data, fill it with the data, then send it.  When received, split it up into the individual values again.  How you actually do all of that depends on what kind of data you are trying to send in the first place (you did not show that, either).

If you want more concrete examples, you need to explain what kind of data you are actually trying to exchange back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use StringOf function. It works with TBytes type.